# Get Header Text of Gridview Cell

Tags: asp.net, gridview, header

I've a gridview in my web form and I'm using a the following code in my web form's Save button:

```
foreach (GridViewRow row in gvList.Rows)
            if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {  for (int i = 0; i < row.Cells.Count; i++)
                {
                    string headerRowText = ???;
```

How can I get the current cell's header text.

Comment: BTW if you're wondering why this loop doesn't hit the header row it's because you're only checking for DataRows. There is a DataControlRowType.Header that is only used in the header row.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I solved it using:

```
  string headerRowText = gvList.HeaderRow.Cells[i].Text;
```

Answer (score 6):

```
string headerRowText = gvList.HeaderRow.Cells[i].Text;
```

returned empty string for me, what did work was:

```
GridView1.Columns[i].HeaderText
```

Answer (score 4):

gvList.Rows[0] should be your header row. You should be able to get

```
gvList.Rows[0].Cells[i]
```

That's just to get the cell itself. You'll need to go into the cell and get Controls[0] and cast it to its proper type then get the Text property.

Answer (score 1):

Set GridView property     `UseAccessibleHeaderText=true`

Then, on code-behind,  to get   j-th column use:

```
GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells[0].Text
```