# Get the GridView Column Header Text - always returns blank

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a GridView that I would like to get the Text of the columns headers from.

```
for (int j = 0; j < grdToDisplay.HeaderRow.Cells.Count; j++)
{
    string s = grdToDisplay.HeaderRow.Cells[j].Text.ToString(); //Returns ""
    s = grdToDisplay.HeaderRow.Cells[j].Text; //Returns ""
    s = grdToDisplay.Rows[0].Cells[j].Text; //Returns text from first row of results not the header
   // s = grdToDisplay.Columns[j].HeaderText.ToString(); // does not work as column count is 0
}
```

The GridView contents are generated at runtime based on a user query. The header is click-able to sort.

How can I loop the GridView and list the column header text?

Comment: When is this code running, i.e., what event?

Comment: gridview1.Columns[ColumnIndex].HeaderText = "Header text";

Comment: the code is running at the end of the Page_Load

Comment: @krshekhar - I'm not sure what header capion is?. your second idea wont help as I'm trying to get not set the text

Comment: soory that was my mistake.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`GridViewColumn.HeaderText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datacontrolfield.headertext.aspx)

```
for (int i = 0; i < grdToDisplay.Columns.Count; i++)
{
    string header = grdToDisplay.Columns[i].HeaderText;
}
```

**Edit**:

> but this would give me no results as the columns count is 0

Then you have `AutoGenerateColumns=true` and only declaratively added columns are counted. So use this code **after** you have databound the `GridView`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < grdToDisplay.HeaderRow.Cells.Count; i++)
{
    string header = grdToDisplay.HeaderRow.Cells[i].Text;
}
```

Comment: It may not be clear from my code above, but this would give me no results as the columns count is 0

Comment: If there are no columns, how could there be Column HeaderText?

Comment: @jimmy: Then you have `AutoGenerateColumns=true` and only declaratively added columns would be counted.

Comment: I've just checked, AutoGenerateColumns is true. I tried setting it to false but then nothing was displayed. - I didn't see your edit, let me test that

Comment: Right after the grdToDisplay.DataBind(); I now have your code but grdToDisplay.HeaderRow.Cells[i].Text is still returning blank

Comment: @jimmy: Have you set a valid `DataSource` before you `DataBind` it?

Comment: The DataSource is valid and the grid (with data) is being displayed.

Answer (score 3):

Since header of GridView is sortable, you can get the text of the header from Linkbutton. try this one:
put the following code in the DataBind of the gridView:

```
for (int i = 0; i < gridView.HeaderRow.Cells.Count; i++)
            {

                if (gridView.HeaderRow.Cells[i].HasControls())
                {
                    //when gridview is sortable, type of header is LinkButton
                    // Linkbutton is in index 0 of the control
                    if (gridView.HeaderRow.Cells[i].Controls[0] is LinkButton)
                    {
                        LinkButton headerControl = gridView.HeaderRow.Cells[i].Controls[0] as LinkButton;
                       string headerName = headerControl.Text;

                    }

                }

            }
```

Comment: Like it ..condensed it down to ((LinkButton)e.Row.Cells[3].Controls[0]).Text

Answer (score 0):

I created my own solution based on things i´ve read here and in other threads .. here it goes:

```
public void HideColumnByName(GridView grid, string header)
        {
            if (grid.HeaderRow.HasControls()==true)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < grid.HeaderRow.Cells.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (grid.HeaderRow.Cells[i].Text == header)
                    {
                        foreach (GridViewRow row in grid.Rows)
                        {
                            row.Cells[i].Visible = false;
                            grid.HeaderRow.Cells[i].Visible = false;
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
        }
```

that method straight up hides both Headers and Cells of the column which header name (or column name) is the string parameter passed to my method ('header' param). "HideColumnByName" method is then called from the "DataBound" event of my gridview. Simple. Hope this helps ! It sure did work for me ! :)

Comment: That has nothing to do with the question asked

Answer (score 0):

I recently came across this very problem when doing some recent coding, anytime I tried getting the header text it would always return blank even on data bound events. I only came to the solution when I thought to try converting the header based on the columns own control scheme.

It turns out, making a gridview sortable turns the header text into something else, making it impossible to simply get the information from the header without converting it. My own solution to the problem was to simply have it not be sortable when I asked for the text, but assuming that isn't possible I did come across the solution to getting the text even while it is sortable in another thread:

[ASP.NET GridView header row text empty when AllowSorting enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16268996/asp-net-gridview-header-row-text-empty-when-allowsorting-enabled)

Answer (score 0):

[image]

the header text return the filed name if template column base on data-source

- **GridView.Columns(i).HeaderText**

but if what you need to get header text for column first use that line

- **GridView.HeaderRow.Cells(i).Text**

this link may help you
[Get Header Text of Gridview Cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091202/get-header-text-of-gridview-cell)

Answer (score 0):

```
grdExcel.HeaderRow.Cells[0].Text.ToString();
```