# ASP.NET GridView header row text empty when AllowSorting enabled

Tags: asp.net

I am solving interesting problem. I have a gridview in my application and after button click (in OnClick event) I am trying to get selected row and header row.

All worked fine when the grid was not sortable (AllowSorting="false"). This is the way how I access the header row cells:

```
GridViewControl.HeaderRow.Cells[idx].Text
```

But, once I switched on sorting (AllowSorting="True"), this approach does not work. Header row is created, expression GridViewControl.HeaderRow.Cells.Count returns the correct number of columns, but GridViewControl.HeaderRow.Cells[idx].Text property is always EMPTY! Nevertheless, on the page the grid view is displayed correctly including header column texts ...

I have tried to find the answer on the web but without success ... I have found some similar questions but never answered ... so, does anybody know how to get header row column texts when sorting is enabled?

Thank you in advance.

PS: Do not advice me using of

```
GridVewControl.Columns[idx].Text
```

property ... there are just 2 columns with Edit & Select commands ... rest columns are automatically generated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's because when the gridview is sortable a LinkButton is used.

You need something like:

```
LinkButton Link = GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells[0].Controls[0] as LinkButton;

String Title = Link.Text;
```